# MAX31865AAP+ PT100 Excitation Current Problem

Tags: rtd, pt100

I have a PT100 and I'm using MAX31865AAP+ for RTD-to-Digital Converter. But I have a problem and I don't understand why this is. I use 400R REF resistor for PT100 and the reference resistor current is almost 3mA. The reference resistor current also flows through the RTD. But, most excitation currents should be kept lower than 1 mA because of self heating. Because there is current running through the RTD, the RTD itself will dissipate power through heat.

3 is not suitable for me and I don't understand why MAX31865AAP+ giving 3mA and how can I solve this problem?

Comment: jacks - Hi, FYI I have reversed ("rolled back") your recent edit to the question, as that edit removed important details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MAX31865 can shut down the excitation bias current to the reference resistor (and RTD) during periods when the chip is not enabled thus, the average current into the RTD is very much lower than the 2.5 mA that you say is flowing. This means the self-heating of the RTD is also typically negligible. Of course, if you choose the have the MAX31865 chip-enabled all the time, then you should aim to use a higher value of reference resistor to keep the RTD current below the point where self-heating errors could be significant.

> *I don't understand why MAX31865AAP+ giving 2.5mA*

The bias voltage is 2 volts and your reference resistor is 400 Ω hence the instantaneous current is typically 5 mA but, you are probably operating at a chip enable duty cycle of about 50% hence, you measure 2.5 mA. Try operating at an even lower duty cycle or, increase the reference resistor value to suit.

Comment: Andy, I measure that the Bias pin voltage is almost 2V according to the ground and REFIN- pin voltage is almost 1V according to the ground. If I increase the reference resistor value to suit, does it cause other problems? And I don’t see the anything about duty cycle in the datasheet. How can i try operating at an even lower duty cycle?

Comment: @jacks your MCU timing when it talks to the MAX chip will determine the duty cycle. The read routine will take so-many milliseconds and, in the gap between reads, you can ensure that the device does not power the RTD via the appropriate register.

Comment: @jacks You need to measure the current with a current probe and an oscilloscope, then you’ll see that the peak current and average current are quite different.

Comment: @Andy aka I read everyone use 400R referance resistor in their circuit. If I increase the reference resistor value to suit, does it cause other problems? What does it effects?

Comment: @jacks you'll have to read the data sheet for that. I've never used the chip so I don't know off-hand other than to say that the bigger the current, the better the quality and repeatable is the value that is read by the chip. Low currents will naturally cause the voltage read to be a little flakier.